# Qubes OS installation won't start

Tags: linux, installation, xorg

I'm trying installing Qubes OS on my PC but the graphic installer simply doesn't start (X failed to load) and the textual one return errors and end with "Pane is dead"... My PC have a GTX 1070, MSI Z97 Gaming 5, 16Gb of RAM and an i5-4690K. On my laptop X starts but I haven't tried to go further. The laptop is an ASUS X52JB with 4Gb of RAM, an Intel Pentium P6100 and an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5145. What can I do?

Comment: Try adding *nomodeset* to your boot options, you can find instructions on how to do that by Googling, there must be a billion site teaching that.

Comment: I've tried adding `nomodeset` at the end of the line that I can edit pressing tab on the grub entry but nothing changed. Am I doing it right?

Comment: @TheMoltenJack did you eventuallly manage to get Qubes to start?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the NVidia video card(GTX 1070). Switch the boot to legacy, boot, chose Install Qubes, press tab (or e) and add "modprobe.blacklist=nouveau rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau" at the end of "vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=Qubes-R4.0.1-x86_64" you should get something like:
"mboot.c32 xen.gz console=none ---vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=Qubes-R4.0.1-x86_64 modprobe.blacklist=nouveau rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau --- initrd.img"

Press enter and your installer should go normally.